# How to notify Android that MicroSD is mounted?

Tags: root-access, external-sd, file-system, linux, mount

I manually mount MicroSD like this:

```
nsenter -t 104 -m mount -t sdfat -o rw,gid=9997,noatime /dev/block/mmcblk0p4 /storage/extSD
```

As a result, file managers can work with it. But Android still thinks that it is not mounted. How can I notify it that the card is mounted?

Comment: only first primary partition is recognized by vold